# Set Start and End Date after Initialising DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, daterangepicker

So I have the problem that for some reason I can't set the start and end date for the DateRangePicker through the methods `setStartDate()` and 'setEndDate()'.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious or maybe not. I convert the date to the 'MM/DD/YYYY' format using moment, which works according to the console output. Only DateRangePicker always shows the date from the current day.

This is where I create the DateRangePicker:

```js
$('#date_editDuty').daterangepicker({
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "showWeekNumbers": true,
    "showISOWeekNumbers": true,
    "locale": {
        "direction": "ltr",
        "format": "DD.MM.YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Setzten",
        "cancelLabel": "Abbrechen",
        "fromLabel": "Vom",
        "toLabel": "bis",
        "customRangeLabel": "Eigener Zeitraum",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Su",
            "Mo",
            "Tu",
            "We",
            "Th",
            "Fr",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "Januar",
            "Februar",
            "März",
            "April",
            "Mai",
            "Juni",
            "Juli",
            "August",
            "September",
            "Oktober",
            "November",
            "Dezember"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },
    "ranges": {
        'Heute': [moment(), moment()],
        'Gestern': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Diese Woche': [moment().startOf('isoWeek'), moment().endOf('isoWeek')],
        'Bis ende dieser Woche': [moment(), moment().endOf('isoWeek')],
        'Dieser Monat': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Einen Monat Lang': [moment(), moment().add(1, 'M')],
    },
    "linkedCalendars": false,
    "opens": "right",
    "applyClass": "btn btn-success",
    "cancelClass": "btn btn-default"
});
```

Here is the code part which should update the date:

```js
        end = new Date(info.event.end)
        end.setDate(end.getDate() - 1)

        DateRangePicker = $('input[name="daterange"]').data('daterangepicker')

        DateRangePicker.setStartDate(moment(info.event.start).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        DateRangePicker.setEndDate(moment(end).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));

        DateRangePicker.updateView();
        DateRangePicker.updateCalendars();
```

And this is what it looks like afterwards:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Response @Yogi, but even the JSFiddle is not working like it should. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I would start here: (1) What is `info.event.end` in `end = new Date(info.event.end)`? It needs to be a parseable string representing a date/time. For example: `new Date("2023-04-21T12:23:34.817Z")`. (2) Similarly, what is `info.event.start`? (3) What are `updateView()` and `updateCalendars()`? Where are you getting those functions? They do not appear to be part of [Date Range Picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options). Is this the library you are using?

Comment: More generally, boil this down to a runnable [mre]. Throw away _everything_ which is not relevant to your specific issue, and show us a MRE which _only_ uses code needed to show your problem. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365) to make your code runnable in your question.